# kmeans gives wrong cluster in R

Tags: r, k-means

I have a dataset of 2 columns in R, and am trying to using kmeans to cluster the data set. The command I use is

`kk <- kmeans(ageincome, center=4, iter.max=500, nstart=100)`

When I plot the result, what I observe from the plot is that R only cluster the data set by using income, rather than age and income. I tried different `algorithm`, `iter.max` and `nstart`, but R gives the same result no matter what combination of parameters I used.

Could any one help me on this? dput(ageincome) is available at http://pastebin.com/2EQx1SwQ

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to use? Only numeric?

Comment: @user1537085 you should post a reproducible example with a sample dataset, for instance using `dput`. Otherwise there is no way you will get a precise answer to your issue.

Comment: @RockScience I upload data onto pastebin

Comment: @user1537085 can you instead paste the output of `dput(ageincome)` into your pastebin. Otherwise it takes time and energy for us to put it in our R. Thanks

Comment: @RockScience I pasted output of dput(ageincome) into pastebin. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to 'normalize' your data before calling `kmeans`. See for instance in the following code I have on purpose applied a scaling so that both income and age have similar range

```
ageincome2=ageincome
ageincome2[,1]=scale(ageincome2[,1])
ageincome2[,2]=scale(ageincome2[,2])

center=4
kk <- kmeans(ageincome2, center=center)
plot(ageincome2, col = kk$cluster)
points(kk$centers, col = 1:center, pch = 8, cex = 2)
```

That is just one suggestion of normalization. You should maybe do some theoretical research to find how you want to normalize the data before clustering it.

Other references:
[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21222/are-mean-normalization-and-feature-scaling-needed-for-k-means-clustering), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19216/variables-are-often-adjusted-e-g-standardised-before-making-a-model-when-is) or [here](http://abbottanalytics.blogspot.sg/2009/04/why-normalization-matters-with-k-means.html)